# Does current HAVE to return to source voltage, or Prefer to?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, power-electronics, electromagnetism

For simplicity I will be specifically talking about a 220V/ 120 V transformer in most residential homes in the US. Under normal circumstance, and assuming neutral is connected, the current flows through Line 1 (110V) and back through line 2 (110V) and the unbalanced load travels through the neutral.

Now what happens if you touch line one and you're grounded? The line has 110 EMF and you are grounded 0 EMF. To my understanding the current goes through you and to the nearest grounding rod that is connected to your house and also to the neutral bar in the panel.

Lets also say you do not have a neutral and also no "ground" in the panel. I have read two explanation on what might happen. In Europe it is common to have a 240V system with no grounding rod and no neutral. Some say you will not get shocked if touching the ground because there is no return back to the source voltage (i.e. the transformer that is producing EMF due to the generator 30 miles away) But technically the ground is 0 EMF and the line is 110 EMF so the difference in voltage should by definition allow electrons to flow through you to ground in an attempt to balance the charges out.

Please let me know if current NEEDS to flow back to the source voltage or if it just PREFERS to return to source voltage. And above all I need to know WHY that is the cause not just the answer. Thankyou for your time.

Comment: Any sources to back up the claim that "In Europe it is common to have a 240V system with no grounding rod and no neutral." ? Where and how common?

Answer (score 0):

Neutral is so called because it has been connected somewhere to an earth or ground rod to "neutralise" it. Without this it can't be considered neutral and must be considered live and fuses should be fitted to that wire as well as the other.

> Lets also say you do not have a neutral and also no "ground" in the panel.

Unlikely. If it's not grounded somewhere then it's not neutral.

> In Europe it is common to have a 240V system with no grounding rod and no neutral.

Nope. While 3-phase systems don't require a neutral for balanced loads, the majority of industrial supplies will have a neutral line bonded to earth and all domestic supplies will too. There may be exceptions in parts of eastern Europe where old installations have not been brought up to current standards.

> But technically the ground is 0 EMF and the line is 110 EMF ...

If the line is 110 V with respect to ground then there must be a ground reference somewhere and this is the neutralising link.

> ... so the difference in voltage should by definition allow electrons to flow through you to ground in an attempt to balance the charges out.

Forget about electrons for this sort of analysis. We just deal in "current" and the charge carriers can be electrons or positive ions. But you've got the right idea that if current enters the body at one point then it must be leaving at another.

> Please let me know if current NEEDS to flow back to the source voltage or if it just PREFERS to return to source voltage.

Current flows in **circuits**. One dictionary definition:

**circuit**
/ˈsəːkɪt/
*noun*
1.
a roughly circular line, route, or movement that starts and finishes at the same place.

Without a closed circuit charge will not flow.